# Messing with initializer_list

Tags: c++, templates, initializer-list

So I tried yesterday to start using std::initializer_list but that wasn't a huge success. There is one of my last try:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

     struct XmlState {

        using U_StateFunc = std::function<void()>;
        using U_MapStateFunc = std::unordered_map<std::string, U_StateFunc>;

        U_StateFunc     beforeProcess;
        U_StateFunc     afterProcess;
        U_MapStateFunc  funcMap;

        XmlState
          (U_StateFunc&& bProcess,
           U_StateFunc&& aProcess,
           std::initializer_list<typename U_MapStateFunc::value_type> mapParams)
          : beforeProcess(std::move(bProcess)),
            afterProcess(std::move(aProcess)),
            funcMap(mapParams)
        {}
      };

      template < size_t NB_STATES >
      class XmlParser {

        using U_StateArray = std::array<XmlState, NB_STATES>;
        U_StateArray  m_states;

        public:
          XmlParser
            (std::initializer_list<typename U_StateArray::value_type> states)
            : m_states{states}
          {}

      };

      XmlParser<1>  test {
      {
        {
            XmlState::U_StateFunc(), XmlState::U_StateFunc(),
            {
              { "Tag1", []() {} },
              { "Tag2", []() {} },
              { "Tag3", []() {} }
            }
        }
      }};

int main() {}
```

[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7U9i6CiNjYsLZaJy)

I'm wondering why I struggle so much to use this. `{}` this is a `std::initializer_list` empty, and `{{}}` this is one with one element right? But you need to put them inside the constructor like `Foo({{}})` ? Or using another list `Foo{{{}}}`. I mean, this looks simple, but I just can't make it happen.

Btw I'd like to know if it's better to use initializer_list or template parameter pack? Both with move semantic, because there is no temporary object with parameter pack after all?

Comment: `std::array` can use [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) but it does not have a constructor that can deal with `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: @super I tried with parameter pack without success too. Do you have any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you change `XmlParser` to take a `U_StateArray` in the constructor, you can make the syntax close to your original.

```
//Changed constructor in XmlParser
XmlParser (U_StateArray states) : m_states{states} {}

//Used like this
XmlParser<2>  test {{

        XmlState(XmlState::U_StateFunc(), XmlState::U_StateFunc(),
        {
          { "Tag1", []() {} },
          { "Tag2", []() {} },
          { "Tag3", []() {} }
        }),

        XmlState(XmlState::U_StateFunc(), XmlState::U_StateFunc(),
        {
          { "Tag4", []() {} },
          { "Tag5", []() {} }
        })

}};
```

Another option is to change the `std::array` to a `std::vector`. Then your code works since `std::vector` has a constructor for `std::initializer_list`.

A third option is to make a helper, that takes an `std::initializer_list` and returns an appropriate `std::array`. Like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932089/can-i-initialize-an-array-using-the-stdinitializer-list-instead-of-brace-enclo).

Comment: Just moving a array, simple and efficient. I was too focus on how to foward the arguments ^^" Thanks!