# Use of common_type_t and enable_if for generic matrix class (via expression template)

Tags: c++

I am writing a matrix library for generic types using expression templates.

The basic matrix class is a `template class Matrix <typename Scalar, int RowSize, int ColumnSize>`
which inherits from `MatrixXpr< Matrix<Scalar, RowSize, ColumnSize> >`

where MatrixXpr is the parent class for the expression templates "MatrixSum", "MatrixProduct" etc.

For example:

```cpp
    template <typename Mat, typename Rix>
    class MatrixProduct : public MatrixXpr< MatrixProduct<Mat,Rix> >
    {
    private:
        const Mat& A_;
        const Rix& B_;
    public:
        using value_type= std::common_type_t<typename Mat::value_type, typename Rix::value_type>;
        MatrixProduct(const Mat& A, const Rix& B) : A_(A), B_(B) {}
    
        value_type  operator()(int i, int j) const {
        value_type out{ 0 };
        for (int k = 0; k < A_.Columns(); ++k) out += A_(i, k) * B_(k, j);
        return out; 
        }
    };
```

The * operator is then defined outside

```cpp
    template <typename Mat, typename Rix>
    MatrixProduct<Mat, Rix> inline const operator*(const MatrixXpr<Mat>& A, const MatrixXpr<Rix>& B)
    {
        return MatrixProduct<Mat, Rix>(A, B);
    }
```

Now I wish to implement also a Scalar*Matrix class. But I fail to define the correct value_type:

```cpp
    template <typename Scalar, typename Mat>
    class ScalarMatrixProduct : public MatrixXpr< ScalarMatrixProduct<Scalar, Mat> >
    {
    private:
        const Scalar& A_;
        const Mat& B_;
    public:
        using value_type = std::common_type_t<typename Mat::value_type, typename Scalar>;
    
        ScalarMatrixProduct(const Scalar& A, const Mat& B) : A_(A), B_(B) {}
    
     value_type operator()(int i, int j) const {
        return  A_ * B_(i, j);
    }
    };

    template <typename Scalar, typename Mat>
    typename std::enable_if < (!is_matrix<Scalar>::value),
    ScalarMatrixProduct<Scalar, Mat > >::type const operator*(const Scalar& A, const MatrixXpr<Mat>& B)
    {
        return ScalarMatrixProduct<Scalar, Mat>(A, B);
    }
```

On Mac and Linux I get an compilation error of this sort:

> template argument 2 is invalid   102 |     using value_type =
> std::common_type_t<typename Mat::value_type, typename Scalar>;

Interestingly, it compiles on Windows.

Any hints for what's wrong would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Complete example:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>



///////////Expression Template Base Class for CRTP

template <class MatrixClass> struct MatrixXpr {
    decltype(auto) operator()(int i, int j) const {
        return static_cast<MatrixClass const&>(*this)(i, j);
    }

    operator MatrixClass& () {
        return static_cast<MatrixClass&>(*this);
    }
    operator const MatrixClass& () const {
        return static_cast<const MatrixClass&>(*this);
    }


    int Rows()
    {
        return static_cast<MatrixClass&>(*this).Rows();
    }
    int Columns()
    {
        return static_cast<MatrixClass&>(*this).Columns();
    }
    int Rows() const
    {
        return static_cast<const MatrixClass&>(*this).Rows();
    }
    int Columns() const
    {
        return static_cast<const MatrixClass&>(*this).Columns();
    }

    friend int Rows(const MatrixXpr& A)
    {
        return A.Rows();
    }
    friend int Columns(const MatrixXpr& A)
    {
        return A.Columns();
    }
};

template <typename MatrixClass>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MatrixXpr<MatrixClass>& A)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < Rows(A); ++r) {
        os << '[';
        for (int c = 0; c < Columns(A); ++c)
            os << A(r, c) << (c + 1 < Columns(A) ? "  " : "");
        os << "]\n";
    }
    return os;
}


/////////// Matrix Product

template <typename Mat, typename Rix>
class MatrixProduct : public MatrixXpr< MatrixProduct<Mat, Rix> >
{
private:
    const Mat& A_;
    const Rix& B_;
public:
    using value_type = std::common_type_t<typename Mat::value_type, typename Rix::value_type>;

    MatrixProduct(const Mat& A, const Rix& B) : A_(A), B_(B)
    {
        std::cout << "MatrixMatrixProduct Constructor\n";
    }


    int Rows() const { return A_.Rows(); }
    int Columns() const { return B_.Columns(); }

    value_type operator()(int i, int j) const {
        value_type out{ 0 };
        for (int k = 0; k < A_.Columns(); ++k) out += A_(i, k) * B_(k, j);
        return out;
    }

};



/////////// Scalar Matrix Product

template <typename Scalar, typename Mat>
class ScalarMatrixProduct : public MatrixXpr< ScalarMatrixProduct<Scalar, Mat> >
{
private:
    const Scalar& A_;
    const Mat& B_;
public:
    using value_type = std::common_type_t<typename Mat::value_type, typename Scalar>;

    ScalarMatrixProduct(const Scalar& A, const Mat& B) : A_(A), B_(B) {
        std::cout << "ScalarMatrixProduct Constructor\n";
    }

    int Rows() const { return B_.Rows(); }
    int Columns() const { return B_.Columns(); }

    value_type operator()(int i, int j) const {
        return  A_ * B_(i, j);
    }
};




//The following two functions are Helpers for initializing an array. 
//Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38934685/6176345
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t ...Ns>
std::array<T, N> make_array_impl(
    std::initializer_list<T> list,
    std::index_sequence<Ns...>)
{
    return std::array<T, N>{ *(list.begin() + Ns) ... };
}
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::array<T, N> make_array(std::initializer_list<T> list) {
    if (N > list.size())
        throw std::out_of_range("Initializer list too small.");
    return make_array_impl<T, N>(list, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

/////////// Matrix class


    template <typename Scalar, int RowSize, int ColumnSize = RowSize>
    class Matrix : public MatrixXpr< Matrix<Scalar, RowSize, ColumnSize> >
    {
        std::array<Scalar, RowSize* ColumnSize> data_;

    public:
        using value_type = Scalar;
        const static int rows_ = RowSize;
        const static int columns_ = ColumnSize;

        int Rows() const { return rows_; }
        int Columns() const { return columns_; }


        Matrix() : data_{ Scalar(0) } {};
        Matrix(const Matrix& other) = default;
        Matrix(Matrix&& other) = default;
        Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& other) = default;
        Matrix& operator=(Matrix&& other) = default;
        ~Matrix() = default;

        Matrix(std::initializer_list<Scalar> data) : data_(make_array<Scalar, RowSize* ColumnSize>(data)) {}



        template <typename Source>
        Matrix& operator=(const MatrixXpr<Source>& source)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows_; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < columns_; ++j)
                    data_[MatrixIndex(i, j)] = source(i, j);
            return *this;
        }
        template <typename Source>
        Matrix(const MatrixXpr<Source>& source)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows_; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < columns_; ++j)
                    data_[MatrixIndex(i, j)] = source(i, j);
        }


        Scalar& operator()(int i, int j) {
            return data_[MatrixIndex(i, j)];
        }
        const Scalar& operator()(int i, int j) const {
            return data_[MatrixIndex(i, j)];
        }


    private:
        inline static int MatrixIndex(int i, int j)
        {
            return i * columns_ + j;
        }
    };


    /////////// Multiplication operators

    template <typename Mat, typename Rix>
    MatrixProduct<Mat, Rix> inline const operator*(const MatrixXpr<Mat>& A, const MatrixXpr<Rix>& B)
    {
        std::cout << "Matrix Matrix Multiplication\n";
        return MatrixProduct<Mat, Rix>(A, B);
    }


template <typename Scalar, typename Mat>     
   typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<MatrixXpr<Scalar>, Scalar>,      
   ScalarMatrixProduct<Scalar, Mat >>  const operator*(const Scalar& A, const MatrixXpr<Mat>& B)     
   {         
       return ScalarMatrixProduct<Scalar, Mat>(A, B);     
 }


    /////////// Failing example

    int main()
    {
        Matrix<int, 2, 2> m = { 1,0,0,1 };
        auto n = 3 * m;
        std::cout << n;
        std::cout << m * n;
        //std::cout << n * m; // Error

        return 0;
    }
```

Edit:
The above code originally had two problems.
The first one is that my type checking failed to see which overload of the *operator was being used. The above implementation with `std::is_base_of_v<MatrixXpr<Scalar>, Scalar>` fixed it and is is working correctly.
I do not know why this old code did not work. Here is the old version:

```cpp
    template <typename T>
struct is_matrix : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_matrix<const T> : is_matrix<T> {};

template <typename MatrixClass>
struct is_matrix<MatrixXpr<MatrixClass> > : std::true_type {};


template <typename Scalar, typename Mat>
typename std::enable_if < (!is_matrix<Scalar>::value),
ScalarMatrixProduct<Scalar, Mat > >::type const operator*(const Scalar& A, const MatrixXpr<Mat>& B)
    {
        std::cout << "Scalar Matrix Multiplication\n";
        return ScalarMatrixProduct<Scalar, Mat>(A, B);
    }
```

Comment: Your still a bit short of a [mcve]. It can be useful to show small snippets of code here and there if they help explain your question, but having a block of code at the end that can be copied and pasted into a compiler that generates the same error message you get is the most important.

Comment: One issue was that `Scalar` can be either `int` or a `ScalarMatrixProduct`. When it's an `int` you need to use it directly in `common_type`, but when it's one of your classes you need `T::value_type`. Unfortunately with that sorted the next error comes along. You can have a look [here](https://godbolt.org/z/46axdz), it's one step forward, but still not working.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the proposed fix. It made it even more clear what is failing: Scalar should _not_ be a MatrixXpr. The return value of the `*operator` is supposed to detect that (but as your correction shows, it does not succeed):  `template <typename Scalar, typename Mat>
    typename std::enable_if < (!is_matrix<Scalar>::value),
        ScalarMatrixProduct<Scalar, Mat > >::type`  In other words, `!is_matrix<Scalar>` is supposed to be `is_scalar` which is supposed to mean "Not a derived from MatrixXpr")

Comment: I ended up fixing it by replacing the hand-baked `is_matrix` typestruct with `is_base_of`:     
    `template <typename Scalar, typename Mat>
    typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<MatrixXpr<Scalar>, Scalar>, 
    ScalarMatrixProduct<Scalar, Mat >>  const operator*(const Scalar& A, const MatrixXpr<Mat>& B)
    {
        return ScalarMatrixProduct<Scalar, Mat>(A, B);
    }`

Comment: @super When I tried to compile my fix on Ubuntu/Mac it failed (as compared to Windows). Adding the functions you provided resolved the issue. It be great if you can provide your solution as an answer. My question is already modified to only feature one mistake. Thanks again!