# C++ const std::array size from constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, constants, size

Say I get an `int` from a lambda function ran at initialization of a class object. Is it possible to use that `int` to define the size of a `std::array`? Something like the following code.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Test1 {

    public:
        Test1( std::vector<int> vec1 ) :
            nvars([&vec1]() -> int { return vec1.size()+1; }())
        {
        };

        const int nvars;
        // ******This isn't allowed!!!!!!!!!
        const std::array<int,nvars> arr;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4};
    Test1 test1(vec);
    std::cout << "nvars: " << test1.nvars << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am a C++ beginner so any other advice will be welcome.

Comment: no. The size is part of the arrays type. The type of the member must be know for the definition of the class

Comment: There's a difference between a run time constant (i.e. a value which cannot change during execution of the program), and a compile time constant (i.e. a value known to the compiler). Integer template parameters are required to be compile time constants.

Comment: Is there any functional difference between `[&vec1]() -> int { return vec1.size()+1; }()` and `vec1.size()+1`? Edit : I guess it casts to `int`.

Comment: I had an idea which didn't work out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74433344/what-can-be-used-in-the-simple-template-id-of-a-class-template-deduction-guide

Comment: Do have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932089/can-i-initialize-an-array-using-the-stdinitializer-list-instead-of-brace-enclo though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The size of the array is part of its type. You cannot let it be determined at runtime.

You can have it be determined at compile time, if you do pass a `std::array` to the constructor. Since C++17 there is CTAD (class template argument deduction) which lets you write:

```
#include <array>


template <size_t N>
class Test1 {

    public:
        Test1( std::array<int,N> vec1 ) :
            arr(vec1)
        {
        };

        const std::array<int,N> arr;
};

int main() {
    std::array vec{1,2,3,4};
    Test1 test1(vec);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bE3eE47E5)

`test1` is of type `Test1<4>`. Note that `Test1<4>` is a distinct different type than eg `Test<5>` or `Test<24>`. If you want one type to have a member array of different size, make it a `std::vector`.