# What can be used in the simple-template-id of a class template deduction guide?

Tags: c++, templates

[Simple example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:23,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:23,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cinitializer_list%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cint+nvars%3E+class+Test1+%7B%0A%0A++++public:%0A++++++++Test1(+std::initializer_list%3Cint%3E+IL+)+:+arr+%7B+0+%7D%0A++++++++%7B%0A++++++++++++//+See+https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932089/can-i-initialize-an-array-using-the-stdinitializer-list-instead-of-brace-enclo%0A++++++++%7D%3B%0A%0A++++++++const+std::array%3Cint,nvars%3E+arr%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0ATest1(std::initializer_list%3Cint%3E+IL)+-%3E+Test1%3CIL.size()%3E%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++Test1+test1(%7B1,2,3,4%7D)%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22nvars:+%22+%3C%3C+test1.arr.size()+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:57.1764705882353,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:42.8235294117647,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) first, doesn't compile with GCC12:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

template <int nvars> class Test1 {

    public:
        Test1( std::initializer_list<int> IL ) : arr { 0 }
        {
            // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932089/can-i-initialize-an-array-using-the-stdinitializer-list-instead-of-brace-enclo
        };

        const std::array<int,nvars> arr;
};

// CTAD guide                           / simple-template-id
Test1(std::initializer_list<int> IL) -> Test1<IL.size()>;

int main() {
    Test1 test1({1,2,3,4});
    std::cout << "nvars: " << test1.arr.size() << std::endl;
}
```

The `simple-template_id` here is `Test1<IL.size()>`, where `IL.size()` is a `constexpr` function returning 4. It does compile with a hardcoded `4`, but that obviously defeats the purpose.

What is and is not allowed in the `simple-template_id` of the CTAD guide? Which names, which types of expressions?

Comment: Parameter like `IL` are never constexpr. So you can't use `IL.size()` as a template argument.

Comment: @JasonLiam: I already knew that; that's why I linked a failing compile. But your comment doesn't answer the question.

Comment: *"What is and is not allowed in the simple-template_id of the CTAD guide?"* Same as in any other `simple-template_id`. Template arguments must be compile time constant. It doesn't matter if you're using them in CTAD guide or anywhere else.

Comment: As an aside, if you want something *deducible* from `{ ... }` whose size is part of the type and usable, you can simply define a deduction guide from array rvalues https://godbolt.org/z/b5eTPY1G8

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: True - that's deducing an array type, and then using the array type (indirectly) in the simple-template-id part.

Comment: It can be a bit less uncsontrainted if one desires https://godbolt.org/z/noxcfEeeE

Comment: Just look at the deduction guide for std::array.

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that parameters like `IL` are not `constexpr`. This means that we can't use `IL.size()` as a template argument since template arguments are required to be compile time constant.

Thus to solve this we have to pass a compile time constant as a template argument. One way of doing this would be to make the parameter as a reference to an array of size `N` with elements of type `T` where both `T` and `N` are template parameters.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N> Test1(T const(&&)[N]) -> Test1<N>;
```